# Firebase how check path contains value and allow read and write other path

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

At the moment i try to build a **chat** in flutter with google firebase.
Now i would like my database more secure.
That means only **users (room_3) in chat** can read and write data data.

Is it possible to check a path contains a user value
and if the user value is contains allow read a other path?

Here my database structer:

**/chat/product_id/product_id_12345/chat_room_id/room_1/message_1/message2...**

My idea is i add in '**room_1**' the user id.
Then i check the user is contains in '**room_1**'.
If the user is contains i allow read and write data the complete path (**message_1/message_2...**).

Here my example:
[image]

If you have any questions fell free to ask me.
Many thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the security rules for the `messages` subcollection you can [read the parent document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents) and check whether the current user is in the `user_id` field with:

```
...
match /messages/{message} {
  allow read: 
    if request.auth != null && 
       request.auth.uid in 
         get(/databases/$(database)/documents/chat_room/$(chat_room_id)).data.user_id
}
```

Comment: Many thx. That's a nice and quick solution :D

Comment: Hello @Frank, i have a other question above this ticket. I have now implement the firebase rules. Now i would like read the data. My problem is how i can get all data from my subCollection. For example if the user write a message i create a new collection 'message'. These masseges are nestle. Is there a way to get all subCollection without colletion Group? Many thx

Comment: If you're asking how to allow a user to read data from the subcollections, that'd be a [recursive wildcard](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#recursive_wildcards) (`match /messages/{message=**}`). If you're asking whether you can get all subcollections while reading the parent, that is not possible: reads in Firestore are shallow. It is common to have a single subcollection for all messages in a conversation, and handle any thread hierarchy you have in there through fields in each message - not more nested collections.

Comment: Okay, thats help me alot. Many thx :D